# WPF loop through textbox controls in grid children

Tags: wpf, vb.net, foreach, textbox

I have a big grid that contains many children as buttons, labels and grids. The last grids of the hierarchy contain textboxes.

I want to loop through those textboxes but this isn't working:

```
For Each g1 As Grid In LayoutRoot.Children
      If (Row.Children.GetType Is GetType(Grid)) Then
        For Each g2 As Grid In g1.Children
            For Each g3 As Grid In g2.Children
                For Each txtbox As TextBox In g3.Children
                     'Some Code
                Next
            Next
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Is It textbox or textboxcolumn in grid ??

Comment: thanks for the quick reply and just textbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only get `TextBox` type children to loop through them:

```
g3.Children.OfType(Of TextBox)()
```

Complete Code:

```
For Each g1 In LayoutRoot.Children.OfType(Of Grid)() //change
    'If (TypeOf(g1.children) Is grid Then
        For Each g2 As Grid In g1.Children
            For Each g3 As Grid In g2.Children
                For Each txtbox As TextBox In g3.Children.OfType(Of TextBox)() //change
                     'Some Code
                Next
            Next
        Next
    'End If
Next
```

Comment: You can not cast a `Grid` to `UIElementCollection`. Why are you checking it?

Comment: i changed it with this line      If (Row.Children.GetType Is GetType(Grid))     I added this line because      i need to make sure that it s looping through only grids  , because at that point the grid has  many type of children not only grids

Comment: You can only select `Grids` as I did for `TextBoxes`. Then you can also remove this `if` check.